# Error reading from stream

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

JIRA issue: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-7420

I'm trying to set up a network of four organisations, each with one peer (set as admin), and an orderer with kafka ordering service along with a client, which makes 7 VMs.

Setting up the cryptographic material, starting every channel (two of them), joining them with the appropriate peers and installing/instantiating chaincode happens with no trouble.

When trying to invoke chaincode, the chaincode can be successfully invoked (status:200) however the results do not seem to be recorded on the ledger. When running chaincode which returns the value for a/multiple key(s), the resulting payload is simply null. This seems to be due to a fault in the ordering service: I get keeping the error message "Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled".

Here are logs for the orderer and endorsing peers of the transaction (which returns status:200)
Orderer: https://gist.github.com/alexanderlhicks/91f32fb5ed2b6d5d232dcdad0572ffee
Peer1 (initiating transaction): https://gist.github.com/alexanderlhicks/a2c7a37d3e692336dbc9a8a9f7fd66ba
Peer2 (has the chaincode installed): https://gist.github.com/alexanderlhicks/75c76b11a26963d7a6962f51295ea816
Peer3 (on channel but does not have that chaincode installed): https://gist.github.com/alexanderlhicks/951757e880d8c2f658d2d188e25b9274

What could be causing the "Error reading from stream" message which seems to be the only error happening? I'm tried playing around with peer and orderer configurations but to no avail. Searching for this error also returns issues in channel creation, or joining channels, which I assume has gone fine since I can invoke chaincode on the channels with my peers.
The txid in the logs is 61f54319421bae9c47fab505e502b932ff6c6b58d7d3795afe1400466e663a5d.

Cheers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with that warning. It's a warning that happens because the client abruptly disconnected the connection.

Can you provide peer logs?

Comment: added in a reply below (too many lines to edit the original question)

Comment: it would be better if you posted the undivided logs to gist (https://gist.github.com/) than post them as answers to your own question.

Comment: I've added a gist with the logs of each peer on the channel, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great, can you find the transaction Id in the logs and add it to the question?

Comment: the txid is 61f54319421bae9c47fab505e502b932ff6c6b58d7d3795afe1400466e663a5d as per the log from Peer1

Comment: it seems the other peers don't get the transaction.

Comment: any idea why that is? there clearly is some information exchanged as the ordering service reacts to new transactions, and does not produce any errors except for reading from the rpc stream. It seems that either something is wrong networking wise and it doe snot receive anything from grpc (unlikely since it receives other things seemingly fine?) or the contents of the grpc stream are causing it to be unreadable?